# JProfiler - "Run GC" button vs Heap Snapshot's "Perform full GC in heap snapshot" option

Tags: java, garbage-collection, classloader, jprofiler

I have the application which creates Class Loader instance (URLClassLoader) and loads dynamically Jar file using it. Next, an instance of class from Jar is created using reflection. Finally, all references are nullified in the way that Class Loader and its related objects and classes are supposed to be garbage-collected.

During profiling in  *JProfiler 10.1.5*, I click "**Run GC**" toolbar button and then I take heap snapshot (does not matter whether "Perform full GC in heap snapshot" option is selected). As I expected, there is no Class Loader instance on the heap, no related objects and classes, they ware garbage collected.

On the other hand, when I **do not use "Run GC**" button, but take **many** heap snapshots with **"Perform full GC in heap snapshot"** option **selected** (with "**Retain objects held by strong references only**" sub-option), I always see my Class Loader instance on the snapshot, along with related objects and classes. They were not garbage collected! Why?

Comment: There could be a delay caused by finalizers or cleaners using the `java.lang.ref` API and clicking on “Run GC”, followed by initiating the heap dump is slow enough to let this processing complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class loader is considered a GC root by JProfiler, the heap walker will not try to collect class loaders.

Comment: Ok, but why? A class loader is eligible to be removed by the garbage collector if nothing else refers to it and its classes and objects. I think Heap Walker should give user a possibility to collect class loaders, or at least there should be clear and visible information about such a behavior of Heap Walker. I had spent a lot of time searching where the problem was, and then it turned out that my code was correct, but Heap Walker gave misleading information.

Comment: Of course, the heap walker will not try to collect class loaders, as it will not collect anything. Your answer is confusing the heap dump analyzing tool with an actual garbage collector of the JVM.

Comment: @Holger Should have put "collect" in quotation marks, but the process is similar